# UPI Payment Integration Response Status Without SDK Files?

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, upi

I am working on opening GooglePay, PhonePe or PayTM app when the user taps on Pay via UPI without SDK.

I know that by following an URL Deeplink like the following, we can open UPI apps for in mobile.

"upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank&pn=JohnDoe&cu=INR"

As of now i am done my project iOS app to UPI Payment app redirect with bill values (UPI ID, Name, Bill Amount) at the same time UPI payment/transaction also debited/completed successfully. Then i am came back to Native iOS App OrderPlaced Method also i am done it.

But my question is how to get the transaction status from there? I need to track which payment/transaction is success and which is failure.

I tried reading NPCI documents, but did not find any solution.

How do I implement that? UPI Payment/Transaction Status/Response/Failure in Swift iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to query UPI Transaction status without any SDKs as querying these need authentication. The best way is to use a PSP like Paytm or Razorpay which already has these solutions integrated.